# How to kill/stop a long SQL query immediately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008 and its management studio. I executed a query that yields many rows. I tried to cancel it via the red cancel button, but it has not stopped for the past 10 minutes. It usually stops within 3 minutes.

What could the reason be and how do I stop it immediately ?

Comment: have you checked that any application is holding this query??

Comment: stop and restart your sql services again..

Comment: i have faced this senario as even i was running everything in sql and it's my wish to edit my proflie or not...

Comment: @user1102001 - not forcing you to do anything. I said can and not should :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> What could the reason be

A query cancel is immediate, provided that your [attention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd341449.aspx) can reach the server and be processed. A query must be in a cancelable state, which is almost always true except if you do certain operations like calling a web service from SQLCLR. If your attention cannot reach the server it's usually due to [scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177526.aspx) overload.

But if your query is part of a transaction that must rollback, then rollback cannot be interrupted. If it takes 10 minutes then it needs 10 minutes and there's nothing you can do about it. Even restarting the server will not help, it will only make startup longer since recovery must finish the rollback.

To answer *which* specific reason applies to your case, you'll need to investigate yourself.

Comment: Note that SSMS shows the query as 'canceled' (As opposed to 'attempting to cancel') only after the attention reply is received, which implies draining all the intermediate results in the communication pipe first (eg. all results in the TCP/IP send/received buffers and all in-memory buffers).

Comment: I wish it would say 'rolling back'

Comment: @RemusRusanu - What if the estimated rollback time is 20,000+ hours? Happy to restore from a backup. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222145/how-to-immediately-terminate-a-spid-with-a-very-long-rollback-time-estimated

Answer (score 151):

```
sp_who2 'active'
```

Check values under **CPUTime** and **DiskIO**. Note the SPID of process having large value comparatively.

```
kill {SPID value}
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, I tried to find out what isthe SPID of the query that is being executed and is suspended, and found that there are many instances of the same SELECT SQL having the same SPID. When I try to execute the command KILL 114   
 - here 114 is the SPID value of my suspended query.
I get the error shon below: Please guide.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '114'.

Answer (score 48):

First execute the below command:

```
sp_who2
```

After that execute the below command with SPID, which you got from above command:

```
KILL {SPID value}
```

Answer (score 28):

This is kind of a silly answer, but it works reliably at least in my case:
In management studio, when the "Cancel Executing Query" doesn't stop the query I just click to close the current sql document. it asks me if I want to cancel the query, I say yes, and lo and behold in a few seconds it stops executing. After that it asks me if I want to save the document before closing. At this point I can click Cancel to keep the document open and continue working. No idea what's going on behind the scenes, but it seems to work.

Comment: In this case the query might actually still be running/hanging in the background, you just won't see it anymore.

Comment: I think it kills the connection, as you do have to reconnect after this.

Comment: It kills the connection to SSMS but not (necessarily) to the db.

Comment: I did try this my sql hanged up. T_T

Comment: If you can't see it, it doesn't exist.

Comment: This happened for me when I cancelled a query that contained a while loop and and commit transaction. Until I closed the ssms document / window, it didn't execute the 'COMMIT TRANSACTION' of the current loop, and just sat there frozen.

Answer (score 24):

If you cancel and see that run

```
 sp_who2 'active'
```

(Activity Monitor won't be available on old sql server 2000   FYI  )

**Spot the SPID you wish to kill   e.g.   81**

```
Kill 81
```

Run the   `sp_who2 'active'`  again and you will probably notice it is sleeping  ... rolling back

To get the STATUS run again the KILL

```
Kill 81
```

Then you will get a message like this

```
 SPID 81: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 63%. Estimated time remaining: 992 seconds.
```

Comment: I had to run `KILL {spid} WITH STATUSONLY` to see the status message.

Answer (score 20):

1. First, you need to display/check all running queries using below query-

   ```
   SELECT text, GETDATE(), *
   FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
   ```
2. Find `Session-Id` and `Description` for respective all running queries and then copy specific query's Session-Id which you want to kill/stop immediately.
3. Kill/stop specific query using Session-Id using this query:

   ```
   Kill Session-id
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   kill 125 --125 is my Session-Id
   ```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 15):

You can use a keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> to stop the query execution. However, this may not succeed in all cases.

Comment: This one is worked for me in Management studio. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I Have Been suffering from same thing since long time. It specially happens when you're connected to remote server(Which might be slow), or you have poor network connection. 
I doubt if Microsoft knows what the right answer is.

But since I've tried to find the solution. Only 1 layman approach worked

- Click the close button over the tab of query which you are being suffered of.
  After a while (If Microsoft is not harsh on you !!!) you might get a window asking this

**"The query is currently executing. Do you want to cancel the query?"**

- Click on "Yes"
- After a while it will ask to whether you want to save this query or not?
- Click on "Cancel"

And post that, may be you're studio is stable again to execute your query.

What it does in background is disconnecting your query window with the connection. So for running the query again, it will take time for connecting the remote server again. But trust me this trade-off is far better than the suffering of seeing that timer which runs for eternity.

**PS:** This works for me, Kudos if works for you too. !!!

Comment: Still worked for me and solved my problem as of -->

Answer (score 2):

apparently on sql server 2008 r2 64bit, with long running query from IIS the kill spid doesn't seem to work, the query just gets restarted again and again.  and it seems to be reusing the spid's.  the query is causing sql server to take like 35% cpu constantly and hang the website.  I'm guessing bc/ it can't respond to other queries for logging in

Comment: I'd love to see a source for this.

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer, if the red "stop" box is not working, is to try pressing the "Ctrl + Break" buttons on the keyboard.

If you are running SQL Server on Linux, there is an app you can add to your systray called "killall" 
Just click on the "killall" button and then click on the program that is caught in a loop and it will terminate the program. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my part my sql hanged up when I tried to close it while endlessly running. So what I did is I open my task manager and end task my sql query. This stop my sql and restarted it.

Answer (score 1):

If using ***[VSCode mssql Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql)***, click **F1**, write mssql in the prompt and choose 'cancel query', as shown in [this thread about the extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/879#issuecomment-584499620).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand. If they were asking how to do so via VSCode then it would be better, but its more about Sql Server in general.

Comment: It doesn't fit all nitpicky details after the main question - How to kill/stop a long SQL query immediately? - that i found via google trying to solve my little variant. And yes, i searched for one question more relatable to my own details. So, when i found the solution to this problem (and this nuance in my client) i added with a big disclaimer - IF using such client - you can cancel in this way. Trying to help others... never understood such zealotism beyond obviously orthogonal answers. But if you think that it'd be better to delete it, flag to moderation, Timothy. Peace.

Comment: Timothy G is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

**My studio version**: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

I manually **closed the computer network card**, and the infinite loop query was successfully terminated!