# Postgres query execution time much longer as a view

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Running the following query on my dataset takes 18 seconds (144/1mil rows match the JOIN ON clause)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_AsBinary(query.convex)) query.convex as geom
  FROM (
    SELECT l1.ogc_fid as id, ST_ConvexHull(st_collect(l2.wkb_geometry)) as convex
      FROM workspace.my_location as l1
      JOIN workspace.my_location as l2
        ON l1.begin > '2018-11-02' AND l2.begin > '2018-11-02'
      WHERE ST_DWithin(l1.wkb_geometry, l2.wkb_geometry, 5)
      GROUP BY l1.ogc_fid
  ) AS query;
```

Creating a View or a Materialized View of the same query hangs/takes far too long.

I have a GIST index on `workspace.my_location.wkb_geometry`

What am I doing that's causing the View to take so much longer than the original query?

**EDIT:**

```
Unique  (cost=41602.32..41602.33 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=19157.904..19157.924 rows=11 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1878475 read=972480
  ->  Sort  (cost=41602.32..41602.33 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=19157.901..19157.906 rows=144 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (st_asbinary(query.convex))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 99kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1878475 read=972480
        ->  Subquery Scan on query  (cost=41602.25..41602.31 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=19141.356..19157.756 rows=144 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1878472 read=972480
              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=41602.25..41602.28 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=19141.348..19157.670 rows=144 loops=1)
                    Group Key: l1.ogc_fid
                    Buffers: shared hit=1878472 read=972480
                    ->  Sort  (cost=41602.25..41602.26 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=19141.070..19141.989 rows=18290 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: l1.ogc_fid
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2197kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=1878472 read=972480
                          ->  Gather  (cost=1005.05..41602.24 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=277.653..19137.045 rows=18290 loops=1)
                                Workers Planned: 2
                                Workers Launched: 2
                                Buffers: shared hit=1878469 read=972480
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.05..40602.14 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=256.904..12387.730 rows=6097 loops=3)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1878469 read=972480
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_location l1  (cost=0.00..20096.99 rows=71 width=36) (actual time=84.221..84.347 rows=48 loops=3)
                                            Filter: (begin > '2018-11-02 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 361232
                                            Buffers: shared hit=11182 read=3270
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_location l2  (cost=5.05..288.79 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=95.477..256.298 rows=127 loops=144)
                                            Recheck Cond: (wkb_geometry && st_expand(l1.wkb_geometry, '5'::double precision))
                                            Filter: ((begin > '2018-11-02 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (l1.wkb_geometry && st_expand(wkb_geometry, '5'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(l1.wkb_geometry, wkb_geometry, '5'::double precision))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1012330
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1014458
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1867287 read=969210
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_location_wkb_geometry_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..5.05 rows=108 width=0) (actual time=93.447..93.447 rows=1012457 loops=144)
                                                  Index Cond: (wkb_geometry && st_expand(l1.wkb_geometry, '5'::double precision))
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=457478 read=431096
Planning time: 6.970 ms
Execution time: 19158.592 ms
```

Comment: Can you show the statement that takes long? `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output is required for an analysis.

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've applied two changes:

1. Removed the previous index and created a new one based on the query time shown in the output (Based on this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns):

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
   CREATE INDEX my_location_gix ON workspace.my_location USING GIST
      (begin, wkb_geometry);
   ```
2. Found from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346147/why-does-dropping-an-index-take-longer-than-creating-it) that the view I was trying to create was being created multiple times in the background, from previous bad attempts. I killed those tasks

It now runs in milliseconds.