# Session State in IIS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET remoting application which uses IIS inproc session state. And seperately have another server for sql server database. The questions is if I recycle the application pools in my application server, will it disconnect the queries that currently being process in database?

The reason I ask because we have slowness recently (long running queries) in database. So we decided to perform recycle of app pools. And expected to kill the long running queries in db, but in fact it is not.

Comment: _"Our web application is slow, let's recycle the application pool"_ - how would that be productive? If there is a client who's kicking off an expensive query, even if recycling the app pool would cancel that query, wouldn't the user simply issue the same action again?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot kill long running query in database through application pool recycle, because query is running within SQL server.

You can use **Kill {SPID}** in SQL server as mentioned here: [How to kill/stop a long SQL query immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921458/how-to-kill-stop-a-long-sql-query-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

No it will not disconnect with SQL server. because the query's are running on different server.